# Convert .NET type to netCOBOL

Tags: .net, type-conversion, netcobol

I have a method that returns `System.Object[]` in an external library.

In the example in Vb.NET, it works perfectly:

```
Dim text = TEF.Cupons(I)
```

> Type of 'text' is System.Object[]

In COBOL, when calling the method, type conversion error is returned:

```
INVOKE OBJ-TEF "Cupons" using W-NUM RETURNING OBJ-RET
```

> Type of OBJ-RET is PIC N

**How to convert `System.Object[]` to `PIC N`?**

---

I already tried this:

```
 REPOSITORY.
       CLASS SysString   AS "System.String".
```

But I get the following error:

```
JMN1750I-S  REPOSITORY FILE OF CLASS 'SYSTEM.STRING' IS NOT ALLOCATED.
STATISTICS: HIGHEST SEVERITY CODE=S, PROGRAM UNIT=1
```